# How to log in as Partner Community user

Tags: community, partner-communities

I am system admin of the org where we have 3 partner community users. I just wanted to login as one of them and see what they generally see upon login.

I have checked that my user (being an system admin) has Manage user permission, Also the role of my user is the one to whom partner users role report to. On partner user record i don't see Login button.

So how do i login as Partner portal user?

Comment: You would need to go to the Contact associated to the partner user and login via the `Manage External User` button

Answer (score 4):

Anybody who is wondering same...please follow these steps:
1) Go to that partner user record
2) click on contact record there
3) On top you will find button Manage External user....click on it
4) Now you will get option to login as partner user

Thanks a lot for this solution @anamadeya